# Hive float data type with unix timestamp

Tags: hadoop, hive, floating-point, hiveql

I am using hive external table with float data type (by Mistake) to store Unix epoch timestsamp.

When I issue where clause on hive external table it returns some odd results. As an example.

```
select event_time from tbl_name where event_time=1478649561 limit 10
```

Output :

> 1478649600

Could anyone help me to understand what's wrong in this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not so much a Hive issue as it is a general issue of floating-point precision.  You are seeing the effect of 1478649561 (an integral type) being approximated in floating-point representation to fit into the 32-bit Java float type.

To see this in a simpler form, outside the context of Hive, here is a sample Scala REPL session that converts 1478649561 to a Java `Float` and prints the result.

```
scala> printf("%f", new java.lang.Float(1478649561))
1478649600.000000
```

As you can see, this was approximated to 1478649600.  There is no way to avoid this if the data is stored as a 32-bit floating point number.

I highly suggest storing the data in an integral type or the `DATE` type to avoid this problem.  The Apache Hive documentation on [Hive Data Types](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types) discusses the different data types in detail.  If you're interested in digging into the full details of floating-point precision, the Wikipedia [Floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) article is a decent starting point.